# Nullpointerexception while ionic cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Getting nullpointerexception when executing ionic cordova run android:

```
E:\Workspace\Angular\myTabs>ionic cordova run android --device
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve
--externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[13:31:48]  build dev started ...
[13:31:49]  clean started ...
[13:31:49]  clean finished in 18 ms
[13:31:49]  copy started ...
[13:31:49]  transpile started ...
[13:32:04]  transpile finished in 14.96 s
[13:32:04]  preprocess started ...
[13:32:04]  deeplinks started ...
[13:32:04]  deeplinks finished in 61 ms
[13:32:04]  preprocess finished in 66 ms
[13:32:04]  webpack started ...
[13:32:05]  copy finished in 16.44 s
[13:32:45]  webpack finished in 41.65 s
[13:32:45]  sass started ...
[13:32:50]  sass finished in 4.80 s
[13:32:50]  postprocess started ...
[13:32:50]  postprocess finished in 17 ms
[13:32:50]  lint started ...
[13:32:50]  build dev finished in 61.72 s
> cordova run android --device
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ghanendra\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
[13:33:03]  lint finished in 12.38 s
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.
doLast(Action) instead.
at build_1n7tz8l3280mv8kwgyclznwu1.run(E:\Workspace\Angular\myTabs\platforms\android\build.gradle:137)
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26 in C:\Users\ghanendra\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses

License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26".


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.785 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code 1).
```

I have been searching for a solution, tried manually adding gradle to following path by running `gradle wrapper` command:

```
C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\gradle
```

Also tried the instructions given at this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html)

Updated all sdk tools using sdk manager inside the android studio.

I have android studio installed(also able to build andriod native apps using it) and path to sdk tools and ANDRIOD_HOME configured inside the system environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ cordova rm platform android && cordova add platform android
```